# Hatching features in layer using QGIS (GPS Track Show Distances)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, symbology

In ArcGIS Desktop there is an option called "Hatching features in a layer".

This option shows a symbol in the definition of the layer every x meters, and shows wich distance of the line is this point.
The only requirement is that it has to be a PolylineZM.
You don't need to find a feature each x meters.

I have seen that in QGIS you can show an element every x meters, but it does not indicate what meter of the line you are on.

This is the option in ArcGIS Desktop:

[image: Option in ArcGis]

This is the result:

[image]

You can configure how often the symbol is seen depending on the zoom:

[image]

---

I have managed to display the x and y coordinates of each point on the line. But I don't know how to show coordinate m .
There is an option called "m" but it gives null value

[image]

This is the option:

[image]

---

In this post of Anita Graser is part of solution:

https://anitagraser.com/2018/05/09/movement-data-in-gis-13-timestamp-labels-for-trajectories/

In this example she shows the time that is saved in M-Coordinate.

In my M-Coordinate I have the kilometers of the track, so now I can show the kilometers of the track.

But now the problem is how can I Show only, for example 0 km, 10 km, 20km,....

I have this code:

```
if(round(m(end_point(  geometry_n($geometry,@geometry_part_num))),1) % 10=0,'Km: ' || round(m(end_point(  geometry_n($geometry,@geometry_part_num))) ,1),'')
```

And this is what I see:

[image]

There are a lot of labels in all kilometers, except km 50. Km 60 don't appear.

the values of M are:

For km 10:

9.971457994611619,
10.010272669243294,
10.049427736851628,
10.078717827986582,
10.134048260383972

For km 50:

49.89965861361227,
49.955282766127425,
50.13697156278586,
50.227182220927844

For km 60:

59.649021204083134,
59.90137352805058,
60.451925034363654,
60.49149744738719,
60.53553518812927

Any idea to resolve this?

Now I'm speaking with Anita Graser in this link:

https://anitagraser.com/movement-data-in-gis/#comment-21044

Here is my LineStringZM geometry:

https://github.com/rbenet71/Sharing_Little_Things/blob/master/Python/Qgis/Track%20Distance%20Km/test.gpkg

Here is a part of my code to calculate M coordinate:

https://github.com/rbenet71/Sharing_Little_Things/blob/master/Python/Qgis/Track%20Distance%20Km/Code_For_M_Coordinate.py

Here is the original GPX track:

https://github.com/rbenet71/Sharing_Little_Things/blob/master/Python/Qgis/Track%20Distance%20Km/04_001_Op_52.gpx

---

I discover another function, that creates a point in a distance (10km for example):

line_interpolate_point($geometry,10000)

[image]

If you create for 20km, 30km,… you can have every 10km, but if you want for each km I think it’s a lot of work.

[image]

Is possible to create a bucle for do this?

Or how I call the function “pointsalonglines” from Geometry Generator?
I do the answer in another post:

[How to use a Processing Algorithm in a expression function used in a Geometry Generator](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/365896/how-to-use-a-processing-algorithm-in-a-expression-function-used-in-a-geometry-ge)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the help of Anita Graser and @ThomasG77 I have the solution.

In Symbology we create a symbology Rule-Based.

[image]

Select Option Geometry Generator, select generate a Point, and in expresion insert this code of ThomasG77, to generate a Point Every 25km:

```
 collect_geometries(array_foreach(
generate_series(0, length($geometry),step:=25000),
make_point_m(
  x(line_interpolate_point($geometry, @element)),
  y(line_interpolate_point($geometry, @element)),
  @element)
))
```

And if you work with a GPX Track that is in Geodesic coordinates, @ThomasG77 give me this other code:

```
        collect_geometries(array_foreach( 
    generate_series(0, 
    length(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:25831')),step:=25000), 
transform(make_point_m(
    x(line_interpolate_point(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:25831'), @element)),
    y(line_interpolate_point(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:25831'), @element)),
     @element), 'EPSG:25831', 'EPSG:4326')
     ))
```

[image]

Now to show the KM (every 25km), create a Font Marker, and in the expresion put this:

(@geometry_part_num-1)*25

You also can create a Picture with Km and select create a SVG Marker and the name of the file is km number and in name of file svg Maker put  expresion like this:

```
to_string((@geometry_part_num-1)*25) || '.svg'
```

[image]

Here is the final result Font Marker:

[image: With marker Option]

And this with SVG Marker:

[image: With SVG Marker]