# How to use a Processing Algorithm in a expression function used in a Geometry Generator (Points Along Lines "on the fly")

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, algorithm, function, geometry-generator

I want to use the Processing Algorithm, `pointsalonglines`, in the expression function used in Geometry Generator.

This is because I want to create points "on the fly" along my line and in a equal distance.

The final reason why, is because I want to show the distance of a track every X meters or kilometers.

All is explained in this two links:

[Hatching features in layer using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364736/hatching-features-in-layer-using-qgis)

Anita Graser help me in this link:

https://anitagraser.com/movement-data-in-gis/#comment-21044

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following expression to create the points along the line every n distance (here 5000 considering the layer use meters)

```
collect_geometries(array_foreach(
generate_series(0, length($geometry),step:=5000),
make_point_m(
  x(line_interpolate_point($geometry, @element)),
  y(line_interpolate_point($geometry, @element)),
  @element)
))
```

Alternative if you need to deal with layer projection (needed if your layer is not using meters in particular) considering `EPSG:4326` is your layer projection and your local projection is `EPSG:25831`

```
collect_geometries(array_foreach(
  generate_series(0, length(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:25831')),step:=5000),
  transform(make_point_m(
    x(line_interpolate_point(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:25831'),
    @element)),
    y(line_interpolate_point(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:25831'), @element)),
    @element
  ), 'EPSG:25831', 'EPSG:4326')
))
```

Although it works for a part and I set the distance value in the M part of the geometry, I don't really see how I can then reuse the M in the labels part as you want in the second part of your requirements. Using Font marker can be another way e.g https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/314789/638
with expression `to_string((@geometry_part_num - 1) * 5) || ' Km'`

***Edit note:*** comment from @RBenet made me change the second part of the answer

Comment: Thomas this is what I'm looking for. Thank you so much!!! For show the km I will use the option Font Marker and in the expression I put this (@geometry_part_num-1)*5 || 'Km'

Comment: Tested with `to_string((@geometry_part_num - 1) * 5) || ' Km'` due to your suggestion (had cast issue when no `to_string`)

Comment: Sorry, you have reason. I write like this to to try explain better. I have all explained in this link. Thank you again for your help: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/364736/hatching-features-in-layer-using-qgis/365988#365988

Comment: No problem, we both learn something :) Not aware how to use well Font marker and you how to generate points along line

Comment: Thomas, my original data is a GPX Track so is in Geodesic Coordinates. 
If I transform the CRS to a Cartesian Coordinates, your script works perfect. 
But If I want to make transformation "on the fly" QGIS BREAK with a Unexpectedly ended. This is my code: 
collect_geometries(array_foreach(
generate_series(0, length(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:25831')),step:=25000),
make_point_m(
  x(line_interpolate_point(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:25831'), @element)),
  y(line_interpolate_point(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:25831'), @element)),
  @element)
))

Comment: I also try to put distance in degrees (0.101341795 are 10km): collect_geometries(array_foreach(
generate_series(0, length($geometry),step:=0.101341795),
make_point_m(
  x(line_interpolate_point($geometry, @element)),
  y(line_interpolate_point($geometry, @element)),
  @element)
)) . The result is: 10km is showed in a correct position, but the other shows in a incorrect position.... Any idea?? Open a Question with this???

Comment: Try to wrap with a `transform` expression the `make_point_m`. It seems you reproject the input geometry but not the output.

Comment: I try with this code and not works. I see in Expression Dialog a error that says: Eval Error: Cannot convert to geometry. This is my code: collect_geometries(array_foreach(
generate_series(0, length(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:25831')),step:=50000),
transform(make_point_m(
  x(line_interpolate_point(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:25831'), @element)),
  y(line_interpolate_point(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326','EPSG:25831'), @element)),
  @element),'EPSG:4326','EPSG:25831')
))

Comment: Try `collect_geometries(array_foreach(
generate_series(0, length(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:25831')),step:=5000),
transform(make_point_m(x(line_interpolate_point(transform($geometry,'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:25831'), @element)),y(line_interpolate_point(transform($geometry, 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:25831'), @element)), @element), 'EPSG:25831', 'EPSG:4326')
))` I've tested (and it works) using points with EPSG 4326 coordinates and calculation using my local projection (EPSG:2154) and replaced the working expression with your EPSG code 25831.

Comment: It's incredible!!! Works Perfect!!! For me you are the best!!!! Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Your issue was you were converting WGS84 to your local projection and then converting again the coordinates from WGS84 to your local projection (but your coordinates were not in this projection) whereas the second time the conversion should have been from your local projection to WGS84